# How to insert a php code from another php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Im creating a custom function for my wordpress website that will add a review section below the post content and i need to insert this function from another another file into a custom function that i added to my functions.php. I need to get this piece of code `$buffy .= $this->get_review();` from a different file to work in this function:

```
function content_injector($content) { 
    global $wp_query;   
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;

    if (is_single((get_post_meta($postid, 'top_ad', true) != 'off' )))  {
        $top_ad = do_shortcode('[td_ad_box spot_name="Ad spot -- topad"]');
    } 

    if (is_single((get_post_meta($postid, 'bottom_ad', true) != 'off' ))) {
        $bottom_ad = do_shortcode('[td_ad_box spot_name="Ad spot -- topad"]');
    }

    if (is_single()) {
        $review = //HOW DO I ADD THAT get_review CODE HERE?
        $custom_share = '<div id="title-deel"><h4 class="block-title"><span>DEEL</span></h4></div>' . do_shortcode('[ssba]');
        $facebook_comments = '<div id="title-reageer"><h4 class="block-title"><span>REAGEER</span></h4></div>' . '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="' . get_permalink() . '" data-colorscheme="light" data-numposts="5" data-mobile="false" data-width="700"></div>';
    }

    $content = $top_ad . $content . $bottom_ad . $custom_share . $facebook_comments;
    return $content; 
}

add_filter('the_content', 'content_injector');
```

As you can see i need to add the get_review function to `$review`, but i cant make it work on my own. How to make this work?

Comment: Have you considered [include()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)?

Comment: Yeah couldn't get the include funtion to get the get_review function to work!

Comment: You should place all your functions in the `functions.php` file to make it easier to work with on WordPress. However, `include` or `require` should do the job?

Comment: Well the `$buffy .= $this->get_review();` code is located in a theme file similar to single.php, a file that constructs the lay out of post pages.

Answer (score 2):

Use include to include the file before using any methods from that file.

```
include("file_with_functions.php");
```

OR

Create a class (with filename same as classname).

Include the file.

Create an instance of the class.

Access the method in the class through the object

Comment: additionally if you want to ensure the file is only included once, use `include_once()`.  also, depending on the type of error you want thrown if the file doesn't exist, look into `require()` and `require_once()`

Comment: Where in my fuction do i need to add the include function? I cant add it after right after `$review = `, right?

Comment: you typically add the include to the top of the file though not necessarily. Then you could create an instance and call the method from within your content_injector method.

Comment: @raj, can u give me an example? I really have no idea how the code should look like...

Comment: what is the class in which this function is located?

Comment: @raj class is `td_module_1` which is also name of the file where its located in, `td_module_1.php`

Comment: try creating an instance of this class like $td1 = new td_module_1(); then maybe do $review = $td1->get_review();